Elements coordinates in 2D view with streamingV2 API in Autodesk Viewer
I'll build a viewer and show sprites in 3D and 2D views.
I used a derivative API and everything was good, but I wanted to increase the loading of model speed in the viewer so I tried to use streamingV2 API for the viewer, but I faced an unexpected issue - fragIds in 2D view receive {x:0, y:0, z:0} coordinates.
Please give a piece of advice on how to define coordinates on the 2D views using streamingV2 API.
code I use to find centers where I want to put sprites


        el.model.getData()?.instanceTree?.enumNodeFragments(el.dbId, fragId => {
          const frags = el.model.getFragmentList();
          let bbox = new THREE.Box3();

          if (nfsOnView.includes(el.nf)) {
            return;
          }

          if (viewRole === '2d') {
            const boundsCallback = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.BoundsCallback(bbox);
            const mesh = frags.getVizmesh(fragId);
            const vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader(mesh.geometry, window.NOP_VIEWER.impl.use2dInstancing);
            vbr.enumGeomsForObject(el.dbId, boundsCallback);
          }

          if (viewRole === '3d') {
            frags.getWorldBounds(fragId, bbox);
          }

          const centerOrigin = bbox.getCenter();
          //....below I add viewable to viewable data for DataViz extension and use this center origin
         })



Note: without steamingV2 API in runtime - the function works as expected.
UPD: I figured out that every dbid in 2D view returns fragid=1. So the issue is 2D view is only one fragid when use streamingV2 API.
